# If Cassandra facilitates the use of non-normalized data, how do users edit it without creating inconsistencies?

Tags: cassandra, denormalization

If Apache Cassandra's architecture encourages the use of non-normalized column families designed specifically for anticipated queries, how do users edit data that is replicated across many columns without creating inconsistencies?

e.g., example 3 here: http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2012/07/16/cassandra-data-modeling-best-practices-part-1/

If Jay was no longer interested in iphones, deleting this piece of information would require that columns in 2 separated column families be deleted. Do users just need to code add/edit/delete functions that appropriately update all the relevant tables, or does Cassandra somehow know how records are related and handle this for users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Cassandra 2.x world, the way to keep your denormalized query tables consistent is to use atomic batches.

In an example taken from the CQL documentation, assume that I have two tables for user data.  One is the "users" table and the other is "users_by_ssn."  To keep these two tables in sync (should a user change their "state" of residence) I would need to apply an upsert like this:

```
BEGIN BATCH;
  UPDATE users
    SET state = 'TX'
    WHERE user_uuid = 8a172618-b121-4136-bb10-f665cfc469eb;
  UPDATE users_by_ssn 
    SET state = 'TX'
    WHERE ssn = '888-99-3987';
APPLY BATCH;
```

Answer (score 0):

User need to code add/edit/delete function himself.

Take in to attention that Cassandra 3.0 have [materialised view](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views) that automate denormalization on the server side. Materialised views would add/edit/update automatically based on the parent table.